# How to fix the Disappearing/Invisible/Empty UITableViewCells issue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have two `ViewControllers`, one is `GoalsViewController` and the other one is `AddNewGoalViewController`.

The `GoalsViewController` is useful to delete goals (cells) and to add new goals (cells). There is a `UITableView` and a button, **Add new Goal**. When the user presses the **Add new Goal** button, it will pass to `AddNewGoalViewController`. In `AddNewGoalViewController` users will select workout, notifications (how many times they want to be notified), and how much they want to run, walk or do any other work.

I checked [a tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html) (click on word "tutorial" to check it), and it was helpful. The problem is that it is implementing empty cells. [Download](https://www.sendspace.com/file/fnrc2x) my project to check it better.

Comment: Really didn't get your question. Where re you facing problem on tableview or addgoals and what is the issue

Comment: There was a problem? Wich problem?

Comment: You should show your code(may upload in google drive and provide a link) and state exactly what is the problem you face.

Comment: Even after downloading the code I still can't understand your problem. You haven't added any datasource or delegate for tableView in goalViewController. Also in AddNewGoalsViewController you haven't added any code for UIButton's action. What are you trying to explain us? Could you please update?

Comment: so where does the edit/delete part comes as mentioned in the question title? if you want to add the the row when user click on the 'Add' and select goal

Comment: I tried looking into your code but it's just too much information missing. Need your story board to comprehend what you need.

Comment: @EminEmini I FOUND THE ISSUE ! I edited my answer. Your project works on my end now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: After spending A LOT of time looking into your project, I found the issue.**

Click on your Main.Storyboard file. Click on the file inspector. Uncheck Size Classes. Done. Your project works !

This seems to be an XCode bug. If you check again Size Classes, your project should still work.

The fix is therefore to uncheck and then check Size Classes in the File Inspector of your Main.storyboard file.

**NONETHELESS: My syntax advice is still valid, it makes for cleaner code:**

Well, did you check [the solution of the exercise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1)?

There is a link at the end of the page ;)

1st Difference:

```
var workouts = [Workout]()

var numbers = [Workout]()

func loadSampleMeals() {
    let workouts1 = Workout(name: "Run", number: "1000")!

    let workouts2 = Workout(name: "Walk", number: "2000")!

    let workouts3 = Workout(name: "Push-Ups", number: "20")!

    workouts += [workouts1, workouts2, workouts3]
    numbers += [workouts1, workouts2, workouts3]
}
```

should be:

```
var workouts = [Workout]()

func loadSampleMeals() {
    let workouts1 = Workout(name: "Run", number: "1000")!

    let workouts2 = Workout(name: "Walk", number: "2000")!

    let workouts3 = Workout(name: "Push-Ups", number: "20")!

    workouts += [workouts1, workouts2, workouts3]
}
```

2nd Difference:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "DhikrTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GoalsTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let dhikr = workouts[indexPath.row]
    let number = numbers[indexPath.row]


    cell.nameLabel.text = dhikr.name
    cell.numberLabel.text = number.number
    //cell.photoImageView.image = dhikr.photo
    //cell.ratingControl.rating = dhikr.rating

    return cell
}
```

should be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "DhikrTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GoalsTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let dhikr = workouts[indexPath.row]


    cell.nameLabel.text = dhikr.name
    cell.numberLabel.text = dhikr.number
    //cell.photoImageView.image = dhikr.photo
    //cell.ratingControl.rating = dhikr.rating

    return cell
}
```

P.S.:

```
class Workout {
    // MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    //var notifications: Int
    var number: Int

    // MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String, number: Int) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        //self.notifications = notifications
        self.number = number

        // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
        if name.isEmpty || number < 0{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

`number` will never be < 0, perhaps you meant `== 0`?.

Comment: @EminEmini My pleasure to help ^^